# AWS RDS（Aurora）で使用されているディスク容量はどこで確認できますか？

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

AWSのRDS(Aurora/MySQL)にて現在使用されているディスク容量を確認したいのですが、ぱっと見ではマネージメントコンソール中にそのようなものはありませんでした。
データベースが使用しているディスク容量はどこで確認できますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[Billed] Volume Bytes Used` で確認できます。

RDSの管理コンソールからインスタンスを選んで Monitoring の2ページ目にありました。
もしくは CloudWatch でVolumeBytesUsed メトリクスを検索してみてください。